# Recursive update for the parent rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, recursion

```
CREATE TABLE record (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT,
  count INT NOT NULL
)
```

I have a table defined as above. The field 'parent_id' refers to the parent of the row, so the whole data looks like n-ary tree.

According to the business logic I have, when the field 'count' of a row is requested to increment (by one, for example), all of the ancestor nodes (or rows) should be updated to increment the 'count' field by one as well.

Since this 'count' field is expected to updated frequently (say 1000/sec), I believe that this recursive update would slow down the entire system a lot due to a huge cascading write operation in DBMS.

For now, I think a stored procedure is the best option I can choose. If MySQL support the operation like 'connected by' of Oracle, there can be some way to be tricky, but it doesn't, obviously.

Is there any efficient way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe, if you WRITE a lot more often the READ you should not update the parents. Instead just do the calculations on read? If you changed the datastructure to a [nested set model](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html) this could help with the calculation in a SELECT.

Comment: @user730685 Please use the `{}` button for entering source code. If done this for you this time.

Comment: @cmmi That should have been an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use stored procedures, you will still need recursion. You only move the recursion from the source code to the database.

You can use [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) to store hierarchical data. Basically, you create two additional fields `left` and `right` where `left < right`. Then a node `e1` is subordinate of node `e2` iff `e1.left > e2.left && e1.right < e2.right`.

This gets rid of recursions at the price of higher costs for insertion, deletion and relocation of nodes. On the other hand, updates of node content like the one you described can be done in a single query. This is efficient, because an index can be used to retrieve a node and all of it's ancestors in a single query.